# Java: Handling browser's request in my ProxyServer

Tags: java, sockets, proxy

I am writing `ProxyServer`, firstly I use `ServerSocket` to get `Socket` that is connected to me. Then I get `InputStream` from connected `Socket` and readed it. I have outputted the request of my browser to console:

```
GET http://mail.ru/ HTTP/1.1
Host: mail.ru
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive 
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: p=7nkAAOS6hAAA; mrcu=7D86524D326C5CB36F898F4A4CD9;
_ga=GA1.2.1174941236.1388398432; c=PCwPUwAAAPKbAAAiAgAAcQAAz5QIAgAA;
```

I must create new `Socket` to write this request to internet, but Socket needs port number and hostname(String) to connect.

If we consider that port number is always `80` then from what part of this request I must get hostname? Is this `GET http://mail.ru/ HTTP/1.1` or `Host: mail.ru`?

Also, can I just send to internet only `GET http://mail.ru/ HTTP/1.1` abandoning other parts?

Last question is, should I have to rewrite this `GET` method itself?

Comment: If it shall be HTTP proxy, then get HOST header. And you pass all data to outgoing stream and copy them back to incoming stream. Btw you must take care of chunking to have broad compatibility with browsers.

Comment: OK i will take Host header, shoud I rewrite GET http://mail.ru/ HTTP/1.1 ?

Comment: How rewrite? Just copy input to destination output for basic functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created simpliest ProxyServer. It works not so fast, but works:)

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;



/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class MyProxyServer {
    public static final int port = 8000;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ServerSocket listener = null;
    
    try {
        listener = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Proxy started..");
        while (true) {
            try {
                Socket client = listener.accept();
                ClientHandler handler = new ClientHandler(client);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}

class ClientHandler implements Runnable {

private Socket client;
private Socket internet;

private Thread thread;

public static int threadcount = 0;

private static int buffer_size = 8192;

private static String CRLF = "\r\n";

public int port = 80;

public ClientHandler(Socket client) {
    this.client = client;
    thread = new Thread(this, "Thread#" + threadcount);
    System.out.println("Thread#" + threadcount + " is running now");
    threadcount++;
    thread.run();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[buffer_size];
        BufferedInputStream clientIstream = new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        clientIstream.read(buffer);
        
        String clientRequest = new String(buffer);
        
        System.out.println(clientRequest);
        
        String host = getHostFromRequest(clientRequest);
        
        internet = new Socket(host, port);
        BufferedOutputStream internetOstream = new BufferedOutputStream(internet.getOutputStream());
        internetOstream.write(clientRequest.getBytes());
        internetOstream.flush();
        
        BufferedOutputStream clientOstream = new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        
        BufferedInputStream internetIstream = new BufferedInputStream(internet.getInputStream());
        
        buffer = new byte[buffer_size];
        int buffsize = 0;
        while ((buffsize = internetIstream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            clientOstream.write(buffer, 0, buffsize);
        }
        clientOstream.flush();
        
        clientIstream.close();
        clientOstream.close();
        internetIstream.close();
        internetOstream.close();
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Exception " + e.getMessage());
    }
}


private String getHostFromRequest(String request) {
    String host = "";
    
    StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(request, CRLF);
    String method = tok.nextToken();
    host = tok.nextToken();
    
    host = host.substring("Host: ".length());
    
    return host;
}
}
```

Comment: This was laboratory work in my university. If I remember, that worcked well. just run it from your computer and check it.